# Redirecting to a different page if ID is not available

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons:

```
<a href="#" id="A">Button-A</a> 
<a href="#" id="B">Button-B</a>
```

And some JavaScript to trigger a click event:

```
jQuery("#A").click(function() {   
    jQuery("#B").trigger('click');    
    return false;
});
```

If `Button-B` is not available (for example, on mobile, the button is not available), then `Button-A` redirects user to a different page (`site.com/another-page`). How can I implement this?

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the length of the jQuery object to see whether it exists

```
jQuery("#A").click(function () {
    var $btn = jQuery("#B").trigger('click');
    if(!$btn.length){
        window.location = 'new location'
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: So, do I add the `href="site.com/another-page"` in the `new location`?  How does this work? Thanks Arun!

Comment: @steveKim like `window.location = 'site.com/another-page'`

Answer (score 2):

Check if the element exists and then add the event listener

```
$(function(){
  if($("#B").length) { // the element exists
    jQuery("#A").click(function(){   
      jQuery("#B").trigger('click');    
      return false;
    });
  } else { // element doesn't exist, add a different listener
    jQuery("#A").click(function(){   
      window.location = "http://newurl.com";
    }); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function clickHandler(e){
  var $btn = $("#B").trigger('click');
  if(!$btn.length)
    window.location = 'site.com/another-page';
  e.preventDefault();
}
$("#A").click(clickHandler);
```